# Where to put/ how to overide TokenAuthentication migrations

Tags: django, django-migrations

I'm adding TokenAuthentication to our django project, as we're adding an api to an already established project.

In the [DRF docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) i see that:

> Note: Make sure to run manage.py migrate after changing your settings. The rest_framework.authtoken app provides Django database migrations.

I also see that to create tokens for existing tokens i need to run:

```
for user in User.objects.all():
    Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
```

Good up to this point, but for me the populate tokens for existing users needs to be in the migration.

I see the migration when i migrate:

```
Applying authtoken.0001_initial... OK
Applying authtoken.0002_auto_20160226_1747... OK
```

How can i add an operation to this ([like here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/migrations/#data-migrations)) and where is this magical migration coming from, I can't see it in my version control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let me say that I'm answering my own question, so I'm not sure that this is the best way to go about this, but it seems logical to me.

I found that the migration in question that i needed was `migrations/0002_auto_20160226_1747.py` in the authtoken package.  Knowing the name, i ran a migration in my user model (though this seems a little backward) to generate my tokens.

My Migration looked like this, note the `dependencies`:

```
from django.db import migrations, models


def create_missing_tokens(apps, schema_editor):
    """
    Tokens were added in 0002_auto_20160226_1747, we thus need to populate
    the tokens table for existing users
    """
    Token = apps.get_model('authtoken', 'Token')
    User = apps.get_model('accounts', 'CustomUser')
    for user in User.objects.all():
        Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        # depends on authtoken migration
        ('authtoken', '0002_auto_20160226_1747'),
        ('accounts', '0003_subscription_max_updates_per_day'),
    ]
    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_missing_tokens, reverse_code=migrations.RunPython.noop),
    ]
```